# How to search for fields with single quotes from a postgres db?

Tags: php, database, postgresql

I have a field that may contain single quotes and it is stored in the db with the single quotes. For example the fields may be like this.

1|xyz's friend|21.3

2|hello, tty's friend|42.2

The user inputs a search query based on which the values need to be displayed.

For example if the user inputs--> xyz's which is stored in a variable (PHP)

I can't do

```
select * from table where field LIKE '%variable%'
```

because the variable already has quotes in it. and postgres isn't allowing me to use double quotes around the %variable%

I also tried doing something like this

```
select * from table where field LIKE E'%variable%'
```

to use escape sequences but that doesn't work too. Any help?

Answer (score 8):

Don't try to quote things yourself, use the library. In this case, you want [`pg_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-string.php). So add the percent wrappers and then feed it to `pg_escape_string` and then put the result of that in your SQL.

As an aside, the proper way to escape a single quote in a PostgreSQL string literal is to double it, if you have `"it's"` as a string then the database wants to see `'it''s'` in the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the quote characters with \, eg

```
select * from table where field LIKE E'%xyz\'s%'
```

You should be able to just replace ' with \' in your string before using it.

Also note that it is generally a **very bad idea** to use query parameters entered by users directly in queries. PHP probably has a module that will sanitise the inputs for you; you should use it.

Comment: I believe in 9.1 it will not even work because it defaults to `standard_conforming_strings = true`

Comment: The question already says he is using the E'...' syntax, so \' will work just fine. You could equally well use '' instead of \', whatever floats your boat.